# What design pattern to use for a client of API?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, design-patterns

So I got a remote API specification which I am going to use to create a set of classes to communicate with this API in my application.

Are there any design patters I should take a look at when designing these classes which will act as the API's client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to [Data Transfer Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html), have a look at [Remote Facade](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html) which

> Provides a coarse-grained facade on fine-grained objects to improve efficiency over a network.

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to start with [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to send and receive data, but as more information is required for a useful answer I'll keep it to this.